# How to create admin, student, principal, teacher from devise because they all have different attributes that's why they are different models? Rails

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails, devise, associations

I want to create school management app so that's why i have created four different models are Admin,Principal,Teacher,student because they have different information so that's why i created them , so how can i create them via single "devise gem" please clear my concept about how to associate them, i have tried to inherit them from user with STI but it only save the user attributes on student model and cant achieve what i want to do, there are other models too but they are associated with these four models and i am stuck at this point only ,so how can i do it any advise and idea .
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, site users such as Admins, Principals, Teachers and Students have lots of overlapping functionality, and the only true difference between each model is the privileges they have on the site. E.g. an admin might have full access, a teacher will be able to review tests and students have limited access only.

Because most functionality is shared, it would be nice if they have a common model, lets call this `User` and generate that with Device:

`rails generate devise User`

Afterwards (or, if you prefer, in the create statement), we add a column `role` to the `User` database:

```rb
class AddRoleToUsers < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    add_column :users, :role, :string, null: false, default: "pending"
  end
end
```

Thanks to this role, we can limit certain portions of the site, or certain functionality, from the user. On top of that, we don't have to write the same code multiple times!

You could e.g. check a certain role like this:

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  
  ROLES = ["pending","admin","principal","teacher","student"]

  
  def admin?(role)
    self.role == "admin"
  end

end
```

More approaches are possible, e.g. a binary role , or even another table `Roles` that  has a many to many relation with `Users`, but the example is just to get you started.

Comment: but in my case they all have some different attributes such has the student has a roll number attribute so if i create an user table then for every user i have to give roll number attribute that will be null in case of other model, so that's why i am thinking that all models should be different but created on via single user devise ,your approach is correct in the case of similar data sharing  role, by the way thank you for taking time for my question.